# Not able to display ssrs report under subdomain (virtual domain)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-5, ssrs-2012

I am trying to integrate SSRS report into my asp.net MVC 5 application but ran into some issues.

**Scenario:**
I have two asp.net MVC 5 applications in one solution, let the projects be 1. "**Web - localhost:12345**" and 2."**ssrsreport - localhost:12345/reports/**". I am trying to load "**ssrsreport**" project with in "**web**" project under an iframe.

**Issue:**
While executing "ssrsreport" project through "Web" project I am getting following errors.
[image]

**Technologies:** Asp.Net Mvc 5, c#, SSRS, SQL Server.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to be routing issue that is throwing the 404 error.
please refer the [link](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/using-subdomains-in-aspnet-mvc-DX) provide and revisit the **RouteConfig.cs** file.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); //add this line
```